# Dictionary not read when using GetComponent<>() in Unity

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I have three scripts inside GameObjects strucured as following:

```
GameObjectA
└ Script1
GameObjectB
└ Script2
└ Script3
```

`Script3` has a Dictionary I need to recall in `Script2`:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    Dictionary<string, int> someDictionary;
    someDictionary = gameObject.GetComponent<Script3>().myDictionary;
    //other stuff
}
```

If I call the method in `Script2` in its `Start` method, it gets called and normally, and the Dictionary is read without problems.

However, during code execution, I'll sometimes need to call `Script2` from `Script1`:

```
Public GameObject GameObjectB;
GameObjectB.GetComponent<Script2>().SomeMethod();
```

and, if I do so, when stepping through code during execution I realize the Dictionary `SomeDictionary` is empty.

Is this normal? I can give more information or the real snippets if needed, I find this behavior weird and I don't know if it acts regularly.

Edit: real codes below.

Script1, `PauseMenu`:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject tracksMenuContent;

    public void TracksList()
    {
        tracksMenuContent.GetComponent<PopulateGrid>().Populate();
    }
}
```

Script2, `PopulateGrid`:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PopulateGrid : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private TileDescr _prefab;
    public static PopulateGrid instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Populate();
    }

    public void Populate()
    {
        Dictionary<string, TileSupply> tilesList;
        tilesList = gameObject.GetComponent<TileDB>().tiles30;
        TileDescr newObj; // Create GameObject instance

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, TileSupply> tile in tilesList)
        {
            Sprite tileSprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Tiles/tile" + tile.Key);
            string tileText = "[" + tile.Key + "] " + tile.Value.available + "/" + tile.Value.total;

            newObj = Instantiate(_prefab, transform);
            newObj.Initialize(tileSprite, tileText);
        }
    }
}
```

Script3, `TileDB`:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TileSupply
{
    public int available;
    public int total;
}

public class TileDB : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Dictionary<string, TileSupply> tiles30 = new Dictionary<string, TileSupply>();

    public void Awake()
    {
        tiles30.Add("1", new TileSupply() { available = 1, total = 1 });
        //many more elements, all pretty similar
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah please add the real code, would make it easier to reproduce and maybe we can spot an issue in the actual code that isn't visible in your snippets here

Comment: I just did! You might recognize Script2... anyhow, if you need more details just ask away! And thanks!

Comment: Actually `Dictionary` is a reference type ... you could actually assign it once, store the reference in a class field. Then from which class ever you add an element it would be updated to every script where you referenced this dictionary .. then you wouldn't have to use `GetComponent` repeatedly ^^  But no .. I don't see no obvious reason why the dict should be empty the other time ... are you sure you have the correct component referenced?

Comment: That's interesting, thanks! I'm just getting started and I don't really know how to use the subtleties of the C# language. I'll see how I can modify my code accordingly.

Comment: @derHugo I didn't see the second part! It's weird because when it gets called from the second script in the `Awake` method there are no problems, but it gives me issues when I do so from the outside.

Comment: Also, I've tried referencing the `Dictionary` from the main script with a `Debug.Log()` and it's not giving me any issues, while it does in that second script: https://i.imgur.com/PImgejO.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a possible solution is to use static:

```
public class TileDB : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Dictionary<string, TileSupply> tiles30 = new Dictionary<string, TileSupply>();

    public void Awake()
    {
        tiles30.Add("1", new TileSupply() { available = 1, total = 1 });
    }
}
```

after to use the tiles30 in other script, just call the dictionary like that

```
TileDB.tiles30
```